# Split array from txt file and append \n. Display each entry on single line in TextArea

Tags: java, arrays, jtextarea

I want to open a .txt file, split the contents by the character ` and then display the contents of this array, each entry on a single line to the user.

I have achieved similar with android so my code below is based on that:

```
try {
        // open the file
        File myFile = new File(f + "mx.txt");
        FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(myFile);
        BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                fIn));
        String aDataRow = "";
        String aBuffer = "";
        while ((aDataRow = myReader.readLine()) != null) {
            aBuffer += aDataRow + "\n";
        }

        // String loadeddata = aBuffer;
        String[] splitdata = aBuffer.split("`"); // recover the file and
                                                    // split it based on `

        myReader.close();

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splitdata));
        txtDataWillBe.setText(Arrays.toString(splitdata));

    } catch (Exception ez) {
        System.out.println("error in array building");
    }
```

The array loads fine but displays in the text area as a single line.

My question is, how to I split the array and add a '\n', or is there another way to display the array one entry per line?

Also, can I prevent the textarea from expanding beyond the window that is open and display vertical scroll bars if required?

Thanks for any help.
Andy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop over `String[] splitdata` and combine each `String` using `System.getProperty("line.separator");`

```
String lines = "";
for(String line : splitdata){
lines = lines + line + System.getProperty("line.separator");
}
```

Comment: Perfect, that does just what I want thanks.  Could you tell me how i can automatically add working scroll bars to the text area if the array displayed out grows the height of the Jtextarea?  Android manages this for you with Listview, but I cannot find the same functionality in the JTextArea.

Comment: You can add the `JTextArea` in a `JScrollPane` and set scroll bar policy on `JScrollPane`

Comment: Also, how would I double line space the array?  (I would like to add 2 line.separators, I should have said this to start with).

Comment: Append `System.getProperty("line.separator")` twice !

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html#setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy%28int%29 
and
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html#setVerticalScrollBarPolicy%28int%29